# htaccess mod_rewrite - overwrite multiple parameters and read the non overwritten ones

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got the follow htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-sub-([^-]*)\.html$ /kat-vergleich/?kat=$1&subkat=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /kat-vergleich/?kat=$1 [L]
```

The second one for only `kat` works fine so

```
example.com/kat-vergleich/bla-1
```

is overwritten to

```
example.com/kat-vergleich/?kat=bla-1
```

but the first one where

```
example.com/kat-vergleich/bla-1-sub-morebla
```

should be rewritten to

```
example.com/kat-vergleich/?kat=bla-1&subkat=morebla
```

but it rewrites it to

```
example.com/kat-vergleich/?kat=bla-1-sub-morebla
```

And I also can't get the non overwritten parameters like

```
example.com/kat-vergleich/bla-1?donttouchit=yey
```

I can't get the `yey`

`echo $_GET['donttouchit']` returns nothing.

Help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example partly works and partly I think your examples are wrong. Because you match on .html in your second rule and say that it works, but it can not work.

I see you changed your post in the mean time as well. Which makes it a bit more confusing.

But anyway, this seems to work for me if you add the .html:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-sub-([^-]*)\.html$ /kat-vergleich/?kat=$1&subkat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /kat-vergleich/?kat=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Check to make sure that your dashes -> - are the same as in your text and your URL.

Comment: Thanks now it works, just need to change ^([^-]*)-sub to ^([^/]*)-sub because of the dash in value I guess that's why I edited the question and changed bla to bla-1